# Elasticsearch bool query speed difference in order

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there speed difference in order?

**Example**

```
{ 
"bool" : {
    "filter" : {
      
    },
    "must" : {
      
  }
}
```

and

```
{ 
"bool" : {
    "must" : {
      
    },
    "filter" : {
      
  }
}
```

What's the process of Elasticsearch running queries?

Is this the same query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Order doesn't matters really.*

`Query DSL` will be automatically reordered anyway based on their respective costs and match costs. Precisely speaking, Everything is interleaved and `Elasticsearch` decides on which bits to execute first.

***Conclusion*** :

1. The order in which you put queries/filters in query DSL doesn't matters.
2. User can't control to get filters executed before or after queries.

Refer to the doc for details : [Execution order of my Elasticsearch queries/filters](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order)

Answer (score 2):

Both are same, elasticsearch first execute the filter clause and then run the must clause. Refer [Query and Filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) for more info

As mentioned in filter context, this is the reason your filter clause executed first, and apart from cache, it reduces the dataset on which your must clause needs to search on.

> Frequently used filters will be cached automatically by Elasticsearch,
> to speed up performance

Comment: Thanks! Can I find what you said in the elasticsearch document?

Comment: @forcode just added a link, which should makes thing more clear

Comment: I cloud not find about execution order of msut and filter in the document of the link. I guess older vierion of docuent is different which version do you read?